# Function accepting an array of names and returning a string with numbered names

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I've created a function that accepts an array of names.
I need to return a string with the numbered names.

```
var names = ['Joe', 'Bob', 'Mike']
```

expected output:

```
1. Joe 2. Bob 3. Mike
```

I've tried the `join()` method but can't seem to add the numbers to each name.

```
function nameRollCall(names) {
    var names = ['Joe', 'Bob', 'Mike'];
    var joinedNames = names.join(', ');
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help. There's no attempt to assign numbers to the names in your code.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? If you're displaying them in a web page, use the `<ol>` tag to make the browser show numbers.

Comment: I'm doing a code challenge for school.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use a for loop:

```js
function nameRollCall(names) {
  var names = ['Joe', 'Bob', 'Mike'];
  let joinedNames = ''
  for (let i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
    joinedNames += `${i+1}. ${names[i]} `
  }
  console.log(joinedNames)
}

nameRollCall()
```

Comment: changing `i` to `i+1` inside template literal will serve the output as OP wanted

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.map()` to concat names with numbers before using `.join()`:

```js
const names = ['Joe', 'Bob', 'Mike'];

const result = names.map((s, i) => `${i + 1}. ${s}`).join(', ');

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Neat. I didn't know `map` gives you an index too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.prototype.reduce` for this job, simply append `idx+1` where `idx` is the index of each element before each name from the array and accumulate it into a final string:

```js
const  names = ['Joe', 'Bob', 'Mike'];
const namesString = names.reduce((acc, str, idx) =>  acc + `${idx+1}. ${str}  `, "");
console.log(namesString);
```

Comment: Just `+` would also work without the assignment `+=`

Comment: @adiga good one!  as I don't need to re-assign it again and again.